# Facebook tells no SDK installed for IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, fbsdk

I am building an mobile application using react native and was trying to integrate Facebook SDK with the application to track successful app installs and log events. I followed the exact same steps presented in the facebook docs for integrating the sdk (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios). The only step I didn't followed in the above reference guide is Step 1.

I was able to successfully log events using my android phone and it shows even the recent mobile app installs. But in IOS it isn't working,(no mobile app installs, no launches, no event logging). I have attached a ss of how it shows when I go to event debugging,

[image]

It tells that no IOS SDK is installed but I followed the exact same steps,

Here is my Info.plist,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>newApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need access to your camera</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need access to your photo lib</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
  <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
  <string>XXXX</string>
  <key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled</key>
  <true/>
  <key>FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled</key>
  <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my Appdelegate.m,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] 
  initWithDefaults];


[client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"newApp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(nonnull NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
{
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                 openURL:url
                                                 options:options];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Please note I have created a business app in facebook and has provided the correct bundle identifier.(Even I tested with a public iphone store id and without but the result is same). Any solution to make this work in IOS will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried to run the app again by pod install and then npx react-native run-ios?

Comment: @Jigneshmayani yep i did that as well but didn't worked. Even I created multiple apps in facebook but the issue is still there. Just for testing, I created a consumer app on FB and by using that app id and app name, the logs were successfully displayed in the dashboard for both IOS and Android, but not for business app.